# node instance instantiates undefined entity

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

Sorry, i am completely new to VHDL, and i have these problems, i have read smth in the internet about it, someone told that i shoud complile some entity files too, but i have just one entity file. I have to make RTL simulation of boolean function using structural model of the architecture, so, there are my 4 problems
Aslo i read that i need to make new files for smth, but i do not know for what and what has to be in it

```
Error (12006): Node instance "x1" instantiates undefined entity "AND1"
Error (12006): Node instance "x2" instantiates undefined entity "AND1"
Error (12006): Node instance "x3" instantiates undefined entity "AND1"
Error (12006): Node instance "x4" instantiates undefined entity "OR1"
```

And also there is my code:

```
ibrary ieee;                                
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_logic is                        
   port(
      a, b, c, d : in std_logic;   
      g : out std_logic        
   );
end test_logic; 

architecture structure of test_logic is     
component AND1
port(s, t : in std_logic;
        u : out std_logic             
    );
end component;
component OR1
port(x, y, z : in std_logic;
        n : out std_logic
    );
end component;
signal e, f, h : std_logic;
begin
x1: AND1 port map(s => not(a), 
                        t => not(d), 
                        u => e);
x2: AND1 port map(s => not(b),
                        t => not(d), 
                        u => f);
x3: AND1 port map(s => a,
                        t => d, 
                        u => h);
x4: OR1 port map(x => e, 
                      y => f, 
                      z => h, 
                      n => g);
   end structure;
```

I have tried to change main entity name, but it didn`t help at all, so i am completely clueless what i have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined components `AND1` and `OR1` in your code. When the design is elaborated these components need to be mapped to an entity. So you need to create entites for `AND1` and `OR1` and then also add these entites to your project.

Comment: Thank You so much, but should i put the same code of AND1 and OR1 in these entites or some another code?

Comment: `AND1` needs to define the AND1 operation, and `OR1` needs to define the OR1 operation, in their own entities

Answer (score 1):

IEEE Std 1076-2008
11.7 Component instantiation statements
11.7.1 General

> A component instantiation statement and a corresponding configuration specification, if any, taken together, imply that the block hierarchy within the design entity containing the component instantiation is to be extended with a unique copy of the block defined by another design entity. The generic map and port map aspects in the component instantiation statement and in the binding indication of the configuration specification identify the connections that are to be made in order to accomplish the extension.

11.7.2 Instantiation of a component

> A component instantiation statement whose instantiated unit contains a name denoting a component is equivalent to a pair of nested block statements that couple the block hierarchy in the containing design unit to a unique copy of the block hierarchy contained in another design unit (i.e., the subcomponent). The outer block represents the component declaration; the inner block represents the design entity to which the component is bound. ...

So where is the design entity from another design unit and it's architecture body implementing it's behavior? Where will the VHDL look during elaboration?

We can note the lack of an explicit binding indication for any of these components in configuration specifications as block declarative items in the architecture body of test_logic (before **begin**). See 7.3 Configuration specification, 7.3.2 Binding indication. So where will the VHDL tool look by default?

7.3.3 Default binding indication

> In certain circumstances, a default binding indication will apply in the absence of an explicit binding indication. The default binding indication consists of a default entity aspect, together with a default generic map aspect and a default port map aspect, as appropriate.
>
> If no visible entity declaration has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component, then the default entity aspect is open. A visible entity declaration is the first entity declaration, if any, in the following list:
>
> > a) An entity declaration that has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component and that is directly visible (see 12.3),
> > b) An entity declaration that has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component and that would be directly visible in the absence of a directly visible (see 12.3) component declaration with the same simple name as that of the entity declaration, or
> > c) An entity declaration denoted by L.C, where L is the target library and C is the simple name of the instantiated component. The target library is the library logical name of the library containing the design unit in which the component C is declared.
>
> These visibility checks are made at the point of the absent explicit binding indication that causes the default binding indication to apply.

So what library logical names are directly visible? The only library clause present is for library IEEE which contains no entity declarations nor their architecture secondary units.

13.2 Design libraries

> Every design unit except a context declaration and package STANDARD is assumed to contain the following implicit context items as part of its context clause:
>
> **library** STD, WORK; **use** STD.STANDARD.**all**;
>
> Library logical name STD denotes the design library in which packages STANDARD, TEXTIO, and ENV reside (see Clause 16). (The use clause makes all declarations within package STANDARD directly visible within the corresponding design unit; see 12.4.) Library logical name WORK denotes the current working
> library during a given analysis. Library logical name IEEE denotes the design library in which the mathematical, multivalue logic and synthesis packages, and the synthesis context declarations reside (see Clause 16).

So the only eligible library that would directly visible would be the working library and your error messages tell us that entities matching component names are not visible.

There are possibilities. You're expected to provide context items making a different reference library with those entities and their architectures available for use, you're expected to create those entities and architectures in a reference library (which can be the working library) or you can use configuration specifications to specify where those entities and architectures are found if they exist elsewhere. The latter can be more elaborate when using configuration declarations, which aren't supported by the tool generating the error messages. It's possible to bind to entities whose generic and port clause names don't match exactly. No FPGA vendor currently supports configuration declarations.

Where the latter comes in is Intel Quartus, once Altera historically supports LPM primitives. This Library of Parameterized Modules would be found in the Intel tool having a library name of LPM which can be made visible by library clause when provided or analyzed into a reference library by the user.

It might be simple to write behavioral models for AND1 and OR1 here and analyze them into your working library:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity AND1 is
    port (
        s:    in  std_logic;
        t:    in  std_logic;
        u:    out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of AND1 is
begin
    u <= s and t;
end architecture;
```

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity OR1 is
    port (
        x:    in  std_logic;
        y:    in  std_logic;
        z:    in  std_logic;
        n:    out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of OR1 is
begin
    N <= x or y or z;
end architecture;
```

Analyzing these into the working library allows them to be found as WORK.AND1 and WORK.OR1 (L.C) during elaboration where binding takes effect and default binding is relied on (14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy).

Your test_logic design then analyzes and elaborates.

You could note that port association actual expressions of the form `not(a)` are not globally static and are only available to use in -2008 (or later). See 6.5.6.3 Port clauses where the expression is assigned to an anonymous signal implicitly declared in enclosing block declarative region which is then used as the actual. Prior to -2008 an expression as an actual was expected to be globally static and evaluating a signal (here `a`) is not static.