# node instance instantiates undefined entity error

Tags: logic, vhdl

please I need some help with my VHDL code. I am trying to design a Full adder circuit with 2 half adders. I’m using Max Plus II for my design. I have tried compiling but I keep getting errors(node instance instantiates undefined entity). Please I would appreciate any help I can get. Also, I'm very new to VHDL. Kind regards.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity full_adder is
  Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC;
         b : in  STD_LOGIC;
         cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
         sum : out  STD_LOGIC;
         cout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end full_adder;

architecture Behavioral of full_adder is

component half_adder is
  Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC;
         b : in  STD_LOGIC;
         sum : out  STD_LOGIC;
         cout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal s1, s2 : STD_LOGIC;
signal c1, c2 : STD_LOGIC;

begin

HA1: half_adder port map (a => a, b => b, sum => s1, cout => c1);
HA2: half_adder port map (a => s1, b => cin, sum => s2, cout => c2);

sum <= s2;
cout <= c1 OR c2;

end Behavioral;
```

I expect to design a full adder using 2 half adders and an OR gate. I would also like to view the Wave simulation.

Comment: The cause is identical to [this answer to a Quartus II question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74339602/16145658) which if up voted would promote it's question to be a duplicate of yours. Without an explicit binding indication in a configuration specification default binding is looking for an entity with the same simple name as the component name (half_adder) in any visible library. As toolic alludes that isn't found. half_adder should be analyzed (compiled) before elaboration (loading full_adder for simulation). Show the complete error message(s) in the body of the question.

Comment: @toolic am I meant to define new sets of entities for each component? I thought that was already taken care of once I defined the input and output ports (under '''component half_adder is''')

Answer (score 0):

Though you have a `component` statement which defines the interface of your `half_adder` block, you will need an equivalent `entity` statement (usually found in its own file) to actually define its inner workings.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity half_adder is
  Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC;
         b : in  STD_LOGIC;
         sum  : out  STD_LOGIC;
         cout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end half_adder;

architecture dataflow of half_adder is
begin

cout <= a and b;
sum <= a xor b;

end dataflow;
```

The `component` statement tells your compiler to look for a module that matches a specific description; the `entity` statement actually defines the workings of the module itself.